# Incrementing a number in VIM - and preserve regex pattern space

Tags: vim

I have the following SQL and I need to append an integer to the email address - and increment that number for each record.

```
Insert into D2PROD."FICTITIOUS_VALUES"  values (894735,'John','Doe','U',to_timestamp('07-AUG-58 06.09.58.213000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'23985','563836','563836','5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99','729','1S8I','RANCHESTER','3693','280204','190783','john.doe@example.com');
Insert into D2PROD."FICTITIOUS_VALUES"  values (334045,'Jane','Doe','B',to_timestamp('24-    APR-66 11.07.41.367000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF     AM'),'14647','298783','298783','5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99','229','3904','GRAYSVILLE','5214','301107','280778','jane.doe@example.com');
```

Using the following command kind of works...

```
:let @a=1 | %s/\(\w\+\.\w\+\)@\(\w\+\.\w\{3}\)/\="\1_".(@a+setreg('a',@a+1))."@\2"/g
```

But the results have strange control characters:

```
Insert into D2PROD."FICTITIOUS_VALUES"  values (894735,'John','Doe','U',to_timestamp('07-AUG-58 06.09.58.213000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'23985','563836','563836','5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99','729','1S8I','RANCHESTER','3693','280204','190783','^A_1@^B');
Insert into D2PROD."FICTITIOUS_VALUES"  values (334045,'Jane','Doe','B',to_timestamp('24-APR-66 11.07.41.367000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'14647','298783','298783','5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99','229','3904','GRAYSVILLE','5214','301107','280778','^A_2@^B');
```

I've looked through this wiki page - but I can't seem to get the syntax just right.
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Making_a_list_of_numbers

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an expression in a replacement you need to use `submatch()` to use backreferences instead of the `\#` syntax.

This makes your expression:

```
let @a=1 | %s/\(\w\+\.\w\+\)@\(\w\+\.\w\{3}\)/\=submatch(1)."_".(@a+setreg('a',@a+1))."@".submatch(2)/g
```

Which results in:

```
Insert into D2PROD."FICTITIOUS_VALUES"  values (894735,'John','Doe','U',to_timestamp('07-AUG-58 06.09.58.213000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'23985','563836','563836','5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99','729','1S8I','RANCHESTER','3693','280204','190783','john.doe_1@example.com');
Insert into D2PROD."FICTITIOUS_VALUES"  values (334045,'Jane','Doe','B',to_timestamp('24-    APR-66 11.07.41.367000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF     AM'),'14647','298783','298783','5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99','229','3904','GRAYSVILLE','5214','301107','280778','jane.doe_2@example.com');
```

See `:help submatch()` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is very similar, just make first your search using `\zs` and `\ze` in order to delimitate the pattern we will use

```
 /\v'\zs[^'@]+\ze\@
```

Now we can just type `//` to say to vim to use last search

```
 :let @a=1 | %s//\=submatch(0)."_".(@a+setreg('a',@a+1))/g
```